# How do I determine the class name of a model?

Tags: magento2, api, dependency-injection

This may sound like a completely dumb question, however I have been scavenging the web for answers with no success.

If need to access a particular kind of model in Magento 2, such as a product model, how do I determine its class name? I haven't been able to find any resource that lists out the available models in a default Magento 2 installation.

I understand that to access a model you would use a factory, but since the factory class name is derived from the model class name, I have no idea what to inject into my constructors to access model info.

My apologies if this info is already available in a convenient spot, but I'm struggling to find it if it is. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell, which things you need to access, so any onr provide direct model class name.